# Of T or Of TEntity?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I know this is a stupid question maybe, but what is the naming standard for generics?

Of t or Of TEntity or Of... it doesn't really matter?

I see IQueryable(Of T) but then DBSet(Of TEntity).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft makes the [following recommendations in *Generics FAQ: Best Practices*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479858.aspx#bestpractices_topic2):

> Name generic type parameters with descriptive names, unless a single letter name is completely self explanatory and a descriptive name would not add value. [...] If you have no additional contextual information about the type parameter, you should use the letter T.

```
Public Class SomeClass(Of T)

Public Interface ISessionChannel(Of TSession)
```

I generally follow Microsoft's naming conventions unless I have a really good reason not to, if only because so many other devs do as well, and it's easy to move around different codebases.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx) give several recommendations. Without copying and pasting them here, prefixing with "T" is recommended and "T" itself is appropriate when "...a descriptive name would not add value." Dictionaries are a example of where a longer name is appropriate with: TKey and TValue.

Answer (score 2):

You know, I've always wondered about this myself, and I think the conclusion I've come up with is this:

It should be `T` if `T` is any type, or `TSomething` if `T` has to be a subclass of `Something`.

I have no idea if this is the right "rule" but it's what I've used so far.

Comment: I was thinking the same type of thing, but then in Entity Framework, a lot of the interfaces are scoped to class, so for example, DBSet(Of TEntity As Class). How would you Name this?

Comment: @Sam: "Class" doesn't specify much about how the object should work, or its place in the architecture, but Entity does, so personally I'd stick with TEntity.

Comment: @Sam: Yeah I don't know... I'd probably just name it `T`, but that's just me.